# Realm for Android, can it do slightly complex queries like this?

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to do a complex query like the below in Realm for Android?

Select Id, max(FieldA/ FieldB) from table C (shown here in sql form)

```
Table C definition:
Id          int
FieldA      int
FieldB      int
```

From what I read in the documentation, it seems to be for simple static queries only, e.g.
Where fieldA = ‘some static value’ .

Comment: What is that query saying? Select the record with the largest...age or height from table person?

Comment: Are you trying to divide two fields within an aggregate?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am trying to calculate the maximum normalized value. This can be done in SQL. The question is to do it in Realm for Android.

Comment: Realm can do aggregations... https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#aggregation

Comment: That doesn't sound like a valid SQL query. You'd need to `GROUP BY`. Please show a valid example.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, Realm can do aggregation, but am not trying to do a max(FieldA) or a max(FieldB). If I try to compile max("FieldA/FieldB"), it will consider the whole of FieldA/FieldB as one field and will say field doesn't exist.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It is valid SQL. Group by is not needed.

Comment: You can store the divided value in a field, and update it in the other two fields' setters

Comment: Why can't you get a list of FieldA, and a list of FieldB, then iterate both together, and calculate the max?

Comment: @cricket_007 iteration is `O(n)`

Comment: @Epic And doing it twice is still O(n), what's your point?

Comment: If you do what I said (add an additional field), you reduce to `O(1)`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that Realm is not a SQL database.  It doesn't look like that.  For instance,

`Select Id`

... in Realm is simply

`C.getId()`, or, possible `C.id`.

The only thing in your example that doesn't map directly into Realm functionality is `max(<expression>)`.  Realm does have a `max` function, and, as @EpicPandaForce has pointed out, you can do any computations you like.  The `max` function, however, must be applied to a value stored in the database, not to an expression.